# loop for creating the cross table

Tags: r

I am trying a loop to create the cross table. My data set is :21 columns, 1300 rows.
I want to create the cross table for the column 1 with the column 1,the column 1 with column 2,the column 1 with column 3,...,the column 1 with column 21.
I use the function "table" and try to loop. Her is my code:

```
x=data
for (i in length (x)){tab[i]=table(x[,1],x[i])
```

where tab is the output of the cross table.

I try to run,but it failed. Could you please let me know how to fix the problem?
It give the 20 same warnings:
In tab[i]=table(x[,1],x[,i])
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: What format do you want the output to be in? Did you define `tab` outside of the loop? `for (i in length(x))` will only run once for the value `i=length(x)`. What is `class(x)`? Seems unlikely that both `x[,1]` and `x[i]` would work the way you intend on the same object.

Comment: I didn't define tab, because I don't know how to define while using a loop. If it is a single case, I know how to define tab. For example, a=x[,1],b=x[,2],tab=table(a,b). And for (i in ncolumn(x)){tab[i]=table(x[,1],x[i]). The format should be like a cross table.

Comment: I don't know what a "cross table" is. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @MrFlick - I think by crosstable he/she means frequency table across all columns...

Comment: @MrFlick for example, a=data[,1] and b=data[,2]. a,b have the categorical coding (which is 1 or 2). I want to know how consist between a and b, so the cross table shows how many 1s are in a and b in the same location , and how many 2s are in a and b .Here is a link describe the frequency table [link](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html)

Comment: @vrajs5 yes,it is the frequency table. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps

```
set.seed(25)
mat1 <- matrix( sample(1:10, 100,replace=TRUE), 10,10)

fun1 <- function(dat, colN) {
tab <- vector("list", colN)
for (i in seq_len(ncol(dat))) {
    tab[[i]] <- table(dat[, 1], dat[, i])
   }
  tab
}

res <- fun1(mat1, 10) ##change the column number accordingly
```

Comment: But, could I take a look tab[[1]] individually? for example, I want to look tab [[1]]. Because I want to obtain phi coefficient or cohen.kappa for each tab.  'phi(tab[[1]]) cohen.kappa(tab[[1]])'

Comment: Yes, you can extract the list components. In the example above, res[[1]], res[[2]] etc..  Please provide the package you used for ?phi, ?cohen.kappa.

Comment: Thanks! I typed res [[1]], and it works. Th package is"psych".[link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html)here is the package.To obtain phi, and kappa, I tried before. For example, 'a=c(1,1,1,1)' 'b=c(1,1,2,2)' 'tab=table(a,b)' 'phi(tab)' 'cohen.kappa(tab)'.

Comment: The example you gave Errors:  phi(tab)
Error: prod(dim(t)) == 4 || length(t) == 4 is not TRUE

Comment: Maybe "psch" will be installed under another version R. I tried used loop combine with your codes `s1=rep(0,21)``for (i in 1:21){s1[i]=phi(res[[i]])}` `s1`, but for cohen.kappa ,I can not obtain it by loop. I only can obtain it by once time. For example,`cohen.kappa(res[[1]])`. It showed me Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                 lower estimate upper
unweighted kappa     1        1     1
weighted kappa       1        1     1

 Number of subjects = 1300

Comment: `i=cohen,kappa(res[[1]])`.`mode(a)` [1] "list"

Comment: phi(res[[1]]) gives me the same error.  I am using R 3.1.0.,  psych_1.4.5 on  linux mint 16

Comment: Do you use your example which you provide in answer? Because phi coefficient is only used for the binary data (such 1/0, or 1/2). When I tried your example, it did show the error as your. But, I applied it in my data , which are the binary data. It worked.

Comment: I tried your example and mine.  Both were getting the same error.

Comment: I don't why it occurs errors when you use the package.But, I can use it successfully by your codes then creating another loop for `phi`